# Laravel Socialite initiate credentials

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0

I would like to integrate Socialite in a Laravel based CMS and I try to figure out how would I initiate Socialite to send requests if client_id and client secret are saved in database?

from the docs basic usage

```
return Socialize::with('github')->redirect();
```

and credentials are saved in config/services.php

```
/**
 * Create an instance of the specified driver.
 *
 * @return \Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider
 */
protected function createGithubDriver()
{
    $config = $this->app['config']['services.github'];

    return $this->buildProvider(
        'Laravel\Socialite\Two\GithubProvider', $config
    );
}
```

I would like to define $this->app['config'] on Factory calling

Comment: You should be able to extend the `createGithubDriver()` method to pull stuff from your database

Comment: Or perhaps you can place some logic elsewhere in your application to set the config value before this function is called

Comment: Yeah the last would be the perfect workaround still working on to figure out

Comment: Try adding the logic to the boot method in a custom service provider, that might work (Laravel 5)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use .evn files to store this information, I think it's more secure. (env files were introduced as part of laravel 5)

Answer (score 0):

can you not just create a middleware class, apply it to the relevant route then just set the Config using:

```
$v = Auth::user()->github // or however you work it out, not sure how you've got it stored
Config::set('services.github', $v);
```

Setting config like this sets it for the current request only